# jQuery location, reload when only width of window change

Tags: jquery, resize, location, height, width

I am trying to make page to reload when **width** only changes.

I'm using the following jQuery code - but it does not work:

```
$(window).resize(function() { location.reload(); });
```

This is because it reloads the page when both height and width change.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
var before = $(this).width();

$(window).resize(function() {
    var after = $(this).width();
   if (after != before) {
      location.reload()
   }
})
```